# How to write a deep link in Robo Script?

Tags: firebase-test-lab

guys..

Is there any way to write a deep link in Robo Script?

I would like to do the deep link after testing My Script before Monkey while testing in Test Lab..

Does anyone know?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, there is no way to add deep links into a Roboscript, but there is a feature request for this.